# What effects does heat have on an LCD screen?

Tags: lcd, water-damage

Unfortunately some water got into my LCD screen creating weird dim patches against the bright back light. only the screen seems to be affected, not anything else.

I am thinking of keeping it in the sun so that water could evaporate, or maybe using a hair dryer. What adverse effects may this have on my LCD screen?

EDIT2 : I tried other options to make the water go away, none of them worked. Seems like heat is the only solution, but I'd still like to know of any adverse effects so that I don't damage it further.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a hair drier blowing hot air why not blow unheated air? I do that to my coffee maker's LCD display when it gets water in it. A window fan or desktop fan.

Comment: Tried, didnt make it better